# How to create a disabled account?

Tags: users, accounts

How do I create a disabled account? for example when trying to login as `nobody`,

```
root@miniubuntu1804:/home/hans/projects/evaler/src# su nobody
This account is currently not available.
```

how do I create an account like that?

Answer (score 1):

```
adduser --shell=/usr/sbin/nologin disabledUser
```

can also use `--shell=/bin/false`

(what's the difference between them? don't know exactly, but you can probably get an answer to that question at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10852/whats-the-difference-between-sbin-nologin-and-bin-false )